# How to read configuration file using absolute path?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a configuration file from which I have to read some properties. This configuration file exists in diferent locations but has the same name. I am able to read a configuration file, but only one from my project. I used the following code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "config.properties";


    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

    try {
        prop.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (inputStream == null) {
        try {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have to open the config file using the full path so instead of propFileName="config.properties" to insert the absolute path to the config file. The config file can't be opened if I use the absolute path.
How can this be done ?

Comment: Using an absolute path to access a file is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I have to do this....it's mandatory

Comment: Use url(path in package)

Comment: The path it's outside the package...

Comment: How use `FileInputStream` like that `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(configFile);` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("path");
```

will open a file with an absolute path.

Note: This will only work for a file, it will not work for anything included in a plugin jar.

Answer (score 3):

You can use FileInputStream for locating config file outside of your project path.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/sample.properties");
prop.load(input);
System.out.println(prop.get("test"));
```

When specifying path we need give file name with extension.

Comment: How has the file you've opened been inserted into the `Properties` object in your code?

Comment: @tddmonkey Sorry, I'd missed the line. Now, I've added it. Thanks for pointing it out. +1